# What is the "reset trick" that restores charging on Lenovo Y50-Y70?

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop

Crux of my Lonovo Y50's problem:

1. Finished working for the night with my laptop, I just shut the lid, not turning it off, then plugged in charger (as usual) to let it charge during the night.
2. Woke up this morning, tried to turn on the laptop by momentarily pressing the power button. Weirdly, the battery LED is constantly on (means fully charged?), but power LED turns on for a few seconds then turns off, and the screen is BLANK/BLACK during all this time!
3. Bottom line: The laptop behaves as if it has no battery because it no longer turns the screen on or even the power LED on. Dead.

Unwilling to believe that this very well taken care of laptop just decided to die, I searched for a software/reset only solution, then found the following thread:

[This SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/q/1017516/607891) describes a problem similar to mine but I have no idea what the "reset trick" is.

Where can I find more information about [this](https://superuser.com/q/1017516/607891) "reset trick"? Could this be [this 20 seconds power button pressed](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y50-70-wont-turn-on-at-all/td-p/1789787)?

Or... is this a known problem & solution with this model of Lenovo? (By solution I mean "not needing to ship it to an authorized lab to repair it".)

Comment: The reset trick is probably what they describe, further down in the question, under "Things I tried that helped".